# Error parsing WordPress JSON To Android App

Tags: android, json, wordpress-rest-api

In a dilemma. Few days ago I dove into **wordpress rest API** and thereafter made an android app to parse the feed into a list view. Parsing from the website is smooth but then I thought 'mimicking' the feed into a file and parsing the data from this **.json** file hosted online.

I get this error:

[image]

Please help me get to know why the second way is giving me a NullPointerException.

The JSON feed is basic as any other wp rest say, http://updates.collegespace.in/wp-json/posts/ 
which for demonstration, made it into a .json file https://rawgit.com/ErickPaul/AppData/master/UBC.json

Also here's my doInBackground()

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: And post your JSON as well

Comment: Done. Kindly refer to the above edits...

Comment: Debug and check if `json`,`feedObj` and `aItem` are being set properly. That's where the JsonException can occur.

Comment: Akash... why should it be a problem when parsing from file but okay if passing from site?

Comment: Could you share the code where you read from the file? Perhaps something is going wrong there

Answer (score 0):

After quite a number of tries, I succeded by eliminating the .json extension in file.json and just let the JSONparser get the feed from `url.filename` rather than `url.filename.json.`

Thanks everyone.